# App crashes if null image URL is loaded in JSON object

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I am populating a tableView with objects from a MySQL table via JSON.
The source data are introduced by many users in a web site form, and sometimes they don't introduce an image URL into a field.

The downloaded JSON object are shown in the tableView which rows are configured to show text, detail text and image.

If the object doesn't have an image URL, the app crashes, and I want to show a default image instead, to avoid the crash.

This is how am I loading the JSON data for the object's image:

```
    NSMutableString *logo = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/logos/"];
    NSString *imageURL = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"strImagen"];
    [logo appendString:imageURL];
    NSURL *logoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:logo];
    NSData *logoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:logoURL];


    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:logoData];
```

What should be the best way to avoid the crash and to show a default image if the web site user doesn't include an image URL in the web form?

Comment: you need to check imageURL, if its nil or empty then load your default image.

Comment: Check the image and if it is nil then load default image else your image from server.

Comment: You can also set placeholder image there.

Comment: @Manthan, what do you mean with a placeholder image?

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage for images coming from server. If the image is not loaded from server you can show placeholder image instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use a `if-else` condition, like

```
NSMutableString *logo = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/logos/"];

NSData *logoData;
if([categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] && [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"strImagen"]){
   NSString *imageURL = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"strImagen"];
   [logo appendString:imageURL];
   NSURL *logoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:logo];
  logoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:logoURL];
}
else {
   //load your default image here
   logoData = //default logo data
}


cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:logoData];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//set an activity indicator                 
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSString *imageURL = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"strImagen"];
    if (imageURL.count>0){
        [logo appendString:imageURL];

        //declare logodata as nsdata
        logoData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:logo]];
    }

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //turn the activity indicator off
        if(logoData!=nil)
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:logoData];
        else
            //set your default image.
            });
});
```

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You may try checking whether imageurl is `nil` or in some cases it will come as `null`.

```
NSMutableString *logo = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/logos/"];
NSString *imageURL = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"strImagen"];


if(imageURL != nil && ![imageURL isEqual:[NSNull null]])
{
    [logo appendString:imageURL];
    NSURL *logoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:logo];
    NSData *logoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:logoURL];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:logoData];
}
else{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default_image"];
}
```